# Finding Numpy array content with gdb

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, gdb

I am trying to debug a python script with a c++ extension that takes a numpy array as argument. The numpy array is called times

```
times = np.arange(0.0,5.0)
result = f(times)
```

This is an input in a C++ function that takes a PyObject*

```
f(PyObject* times)
```

is a C++ function (it goes via Boost.Python)

I am trying to debug into this using gdb, but I can't seem to find the data of times. See my output below. I suspect it gets an empty array (as ob_size =0), but I am not sure as I am not very experienced with the C++ underlyings of numpy arrays.

Any thoughts,
Mike

GDB debugging session

```
(gdb) p times
$21 = (PyObject *) 0x7ffff2c9b620
(gdb) p *$21
$22 = {ob_refcnt = 2, ob_type = 0x7ffff5518a80 <PyArray_Type>}
(gdb) p *$22.ob_type
$23 = {ob_refcnt = 190, ob_type = 0x91f8e0 <PyType_Type>, ob_size = 0, 
tp_name = 0x7ffff52d5566 "numpy.ndarray", tp_basicsize = 80, tp_itemsize = 0, 
tp_dealloc = 0x7ffff51d35b0 <array_dealloc>, tp_print = 0x0, tp_getattr = 0x0, tp_setattr = 0x0, 
tp_compare = 0x0, tp_repr = 0x7ffff51d3810 <array_repr>, 
tp_as_number = 0x7ffff551fc40 <array_as_number>, tp_as_sequence = 0x7ffff551fd80    <array_as_sequence>, 
tp_as_mapping = 0x7ffff551d570 <array_as_mapping>, tp_hash = 0x0, tp_call = 0x0, 
tp_str = 0x7ffff51d37a0 <array_str>, tp_getattro = 0x442fef <PyObject_GenericGetAttr>, 
tp_setattro = 0x4272ff <PyObject_GenericSetAttr>, tp_as_buffer = 0x7ffff551b920 <array_as_buffer>, 
tp_flags = 2233851, 
tp_doc = 0xbf2814 "ndarray(shape, dtype=float, buffer=None, offset=0,\n", ' ' <repeats 12 times>, "strides=None, order=None)\n\n    An array object represents a multidimensional, homogeneous array\n    of fixed-size items.  An associated d"..., tp_traverse = 0x0, tp_clear = 0x0, 
tp_richcompare = 0x7ffff51d4750 <array_richcompare>, tp_weaklistoffset = 72, 
tp_iter = 0x7ffff51d3760 <array_iter>, tp_iternext = 0x0, tp_methods = 0x7ffff551da00 <array_methods>, 
tp_members = 0x0, tp_getset = 0x7ffff551c8e0 <array_getsetlist>, 
tp_base = 0x9175e0 <PyBaseObject_Type>, tp_dict = 0x7ffff7e83a28, tp_descr_get = 0x0, 
tp_descr_set = 0x0, tp_dictoffset = 0, tp_init = 0x5112d0, tp_alloc = 0x7ffff51d3050 <array_alloc>, 
tp_new = 0x7ffff51d4d50 <array_new>, tp_free = 0x7ffff51d3040 <array_free>, tp_is_gc = 0x0, 
tp_bases = 0x7ffff7e82a10, tp_mro = 0x7ffff7e8bab8, tp_cache = 0x0, tp_subclasses = 0x7ffff4cc2cf8, 
tp_weaklist = 0x7ffff7e89100, tp_del = 0x0, tp_version_tag = 0}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h#L1453-L1457) maybe what you're looking for?